# expo start Cannot Find Module 'hoek'

Tags: react-native, expo

I installed expo-cli and start project with `expo init`.
Then i try to start project with `expo start`. I'm getting an error: **Cannot find module 'hoek'**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v11.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle empty-project-template@~prestart: empty-project-template@
6 info lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: empty-project-template@
7 verbose lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\proje\hoek\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;D:\Matlab\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Users\Seçil.SECIL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Seçil.SECIL\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Seçil.SECIL\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
9 verbose lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: CWD: C:\proje\hoek
10 silly lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle empty-project-template@~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: empty-project-template@ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
14 verbose pkgid empty-project-template@
15 verbose cwd C:\proje\hoek
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v11.2.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error empty-project-template@ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the empty-project-template@ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried these:

- remove **node_modules** folder and run `npm install` again
- `npm clear cache` and run `expo start`
- `npm install hoek` and `expo start`

Nothing resolves the problem, I'm still getting the same error when I start the expo project.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^8.0.0",
    "expo": "^31.0.2",
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "^16.6.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-sensors": "^4.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Delete your lock file and reinstall the packages

Comment: @RaajNadar I deleted package.json.lock then i run npm install. I m getting same error.

Comment: I had a lot of problem with npm, so try using yarn.. check if you there is a `node_modules/hoek` folder

Comment: One more step try `expo start -c` this will clear the cache

Comment: @RaajNadar expo start -c didnt work.

Comment: @RaajNadar i tried with yarn it doesnt work.

Comment: This is getting complicated, give your OS, node -v and npm -v

Comment: windows 10
node v11.2.0
npm 6.4.1

Comment: I edited my question and added log file.

Comment: Try` yarn start` inside your project also check you expo-cli version

Comment: @RaajNadar I tried it didint work. Can should be a node.js problem. Because i m getting this error before expo project start correctly.

Comment: Try downgrading to node 10 it is stable release

Comment: @RaajNadar i fixed the problem. my expo-cli package has no hoek node module. I uninstall expo-cli with npm uninstall -g expo-cli and reinstall npm i -g expo-cli Missing node modules came back in global expo-cli/node_modules folder. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Cool, Thanks for sharing this info..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to install it using `npm install --save hoek`?
You are leaving out the `--save` argument. This is why the dependency is not listed in your **package.json** file.

Comment: But that should not throw an error! Because the package will be downloaded in his node_modules

Comment: i installed hoek with npm install --save hoek but it didnt resolve my problem.

Comment: @erkandemir I ran through the same steps as you: `expo init`, `npm i --save hoek`, and then `expo start`. Everything ran perfecty. Could you try installing npm's **reinstall** package: `npm install reinstall -g`. Then run it in your app folder: `reinstall`.

Comment: @KevinvanZyl i run npm install reinstall -g  in my app folder and expo start. it doesnt work.

Comment: @erkandemir Now try to run `reinstall`. Once the app is finished reinstalling then try `expo start` again. I copied your **package.json** exactly and ran through your steps without any issues.